# Could a SD card or USB inserted that isnt mounted still be risky to the system if it had a virus?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, security, sd-card

I'm concerned for a potential virus or autorun script that could run on Ubuntu even though the SD card isnt properly mounted.
I wanted to recover some data from the SD card since it was said that its corrupt, and when i put it in, nothing got mounted. I went to check into DISKS and it said the file system is unknown/NTFS.

I know im being paranoid, but is it still possible for an autorun script virus or a simple autorun shell script to run simple commands to copy out or delete all my local files that dont need sudo even though the SD card or USB wasnt mounted??

I just need to know whether this is possible.

Comment: This is more suitable for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: See also: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/91055/ and http://security.stackexchange.com/q/126569/

Comment: Both links are off topic. Provide one about Ubuntu if you want to make a point. I do agree with the 1st sentence in the 1st answer of the 1st link but it is the default in Ubuntu for sd and usb: it will prompt and not just execute.

Comment: BadUSB attacks can be configured to run on Windows, OS X and any flavor of Linux. Taking facts and links as personal attacks is really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no active virusses for Linux systems and I would be more concerned about rootkits if I was paranoid.

Anything that is not formatted as EXT can not mess with your system unless it is an operating system that is on the device and you **allow** it to mess with your system (ie. you insert your admin password and let it execute a file). Other places than your /home/$USER/ will mainly need your admin password to do anything to it.

Besides that: automount does not work unless you set the system up to automount. That would require a udev rule for SD.

If the SD or USB is NTFS formatted you need a windows system for any windows virus to be harmful.

So no, a normal Ubuntu does not allow this. It would require more effort on your part (like providing your admin account when you do not expect it to need to be asked) for an SD or USB to become harmful. And I would assume that extra effort would set of all the alarms you need to stop and start thinking.

And to top it off: -unmounted- nothing can harm you.

Comment: You are kind of forgetting all the attacks based on USB devices acting like a keyboard and sending keystrokes over the USB port. The device could start a shell and type all sort of preconfigured commands all without the user's interaction.

Comment: But that is not a virus ;-) Malware yes, but not a virus.

Comment: The OP asks «it still possible for [...] a simple autorun shell script to run simple commands to copy out or delete all my local files» → Yes, it is if the device is built to do so.

Comment: "Yes, it is if the device is built to do so"Your point being? again: autorun does not work for NTFS. You need to change your system to do so (by lowering security by adding a stupid udev rule on a NTFS). When I type "rm -rf /*" my system is gone. Not the systems fault.  I still claim: -no-.

Comment: My point being your answer does not take into account malicious devices, which are an important part of the scenario when talking about infosec. Nobody was talking about whose fault it is. If you ignore BadUSB attacks they do not magically disappear.

Comment: So all in all, nothing bad can happen if first and foremost the SD Card or USB is not mounted.. right?

Comment: Yes correct. And from a small test: only EXT should be able to use autorun by default (and even then you get a popup asking for it to autorun).

Answer (score 0):

> is it still possible for an autorun script virus or a simple autorun
>   shell script to run simple commands to copy out or delete all my local
>   files that dont need sudo even though the SD card or USB wasnt
>   mounted??

There's two problems with your logic.

Problem #1 : autorun must be enabled in order for any script to run.

Problem #2 : deleting your files would require that the script runs as your user or belong to group that can remove those files. Example, my user trying to remove file from `testuser`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C rm /home/testuser/examples.desktop                                                                            
rm: remove write-protected regular file '/home/testuser/examples.desktop'? y
rm: cannot remove '/home/testuser/examples.desktop': Permission denied
```

My user doesn't belong to `testuser` group , therefore cannot remove it.

Comment: 3rd problem: he is asking about "unmounted devices" ;)

Comment: I would obviously see if anything 'tried' to happen under kern.log and syslog, am i right?